# Print sequence in F#

Tags: f#

I'm very new to F# so please excuse the completely newbie question:

I have a sequence stored in a variable called prices. I'd like to output the contents of this sequence to the interactive window. What's the easiest command to do this?

Here is my sequence:

```
> prices;;
val it : seq<System.DateTime * float> = seq []
```

I've tried printf'ing it but that gives me the error:

```
> printf("%A", prices);;

  printf("%A", prices);;
  -------^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(82,8): error FS0001: The type ''b * 'c' is not compatible with the type 'Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

printf does not take parentheses:

```
printfn "%A" prices;;
```

(See [F# function types: fun with tuples and currying](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!169.entry) for details)

You might also convert the seq to a list, e.g.

```
printfn "%A" (Seq.toList prices);;
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome link. printfn is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can control interactive session printer capabilities by changing fsi.* properties
(FloatingPointFormat, PrintWidth, PrintDepth, PrintLength, ...)
F.e. please see: http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/post/7438.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
> prices;;
val it : seq<System.DateTime * float> = seq []
```

It's doing its job: `seq []` means the sequence is empty.

Comment: Thanks. That explains a whole lot :)